# Batch file to run windows command in loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, phantomjs

the following below code opens 10 command prompt windows. But I am trying to finish one command at a time and start the next in the same window. Can anyone please suggest changes?

```
echo off
SET /a i=0

:loop
IF %i%==10 GOTO END
echo This is iteration %i%. 
START cmd.exe /K "cd C:\bin\phantomjs-1.9.2-windows & phantomjs examples\loadspeed.js"
SET /a i=%i%+1
GOTO LOOP

:end
echo
```

Answer (score 2):

Using your approach, you can use `start /wait` and `cmd /c` in combination to open ten windows one at a time.  The `/wait` pauses the batch files execution until the new CMD window closes.  `/c` tells the CMD window to close when it finishes processing the quoted commands.

```
START /wait cmd.exe /c "cd C:\bin\phantomjs-1.9.2-windows & phantomjs examples\loadspeed.js"
```

If you want to run the ten iterations in a single *new* window, then you need to change your command to something like this:

```
@echo off
start /wait cmd /c "@echo off&&for /L %%i in (1,1,10) do (echo Iteration: %%i&&ping -n 2 localhost)"
```

This opens a new CMD window and then executes the `echo` and `ping` statements 10 times, each time waiting until the prior set finishes before moving to the next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

This should execute it 10 times, one after another.

```
@echo off
cd /d "C:\bin\phantomjs-1.9.2-windows"
for /L %%a in (1,1,10) do (
   echo This is iteration %%a
   start "" /w /b "phantomjs" "examples\loadspeed.js"
)
pause
```